# HashMap<String, Object> How to replace 1 value of the Object?

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hashmap

```
Map<String, Data> map = new HashMap<String,Data>();
map.put("jan", new Data("RED","M4A1",5,0,0));
```

How can I change the value RED of the Data object?, without getting all the information out of the map with the key and putting it back in, like this:

```
map.put("jan" new Data("Blue",
      map.get("jan").Brand,
      map.get("jan").Storage,
      map.get("jan").Sold,
      map.get("jan").Bought));
```

So how can i change 1 value of the Data Object instead of redo them all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on whether `Data` is mutable. For example, you may be able to write:

```
Data data = map.get("jan");
data.setColor("Blue");
```

Don't forget that the map only contains a *reference* to the object, so if you change the data within the object, that change will be seen if someone fetches the reference from the map later.

Or if it's immutable, it could potentially have a `withColor` method, so you could write:

```
Data data = map.get("jan");
map.put("jan", data.withColor("Blue"));
```

Without knowing more about your `Data` type (which I hope isn't the real name of your class) it's hard to say any more.

(I also hope your class doesn't really have Pascal-cased fields, and I hope those fields are private, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP don't want do get operations etc.,

Comment: @Nambari "without getting all the information out of the map with the key and putting it back in" My interpretation is that he just doesn't want to create new objects and `put` them back into the map.

Comment: Its seem to be mutable. the first option did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `Data` is mutable you can set the `"RED"` field:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("jan", new Data("RED","M4A1",5,0,0));
// Later...
map.get("jan").setColor("BLUE");
```

If `Data` isn't mutable, then your only option is to `put` the new value as you have it written.

Answer (score 2):

Add appropriate setter to your `Data` class, e.g.

```
class Data {
    setColor(String color){...}
}


map.get("jan").setColor("BLUE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Data` has a `setter` for the `color` property:

```
public class Data {
  private String color;

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

You can just `get` the required `Data` object and set its property:

```
Data data = map.get("jan");
data.setColor("blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please find the code snippet:**

```
Map<String, Data> map = new HashMap<String,Data>();

public class Data{

private String color;

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

public String getColor() {
    return this.color;
  }

publicData(String color){
this.setColor(color);
}
}


map.put("jan", new Data("RED","M4A1",5,0,0));
```

**Now you may do like this:**

```
Data data = map.get("jan");
data.setColor("black");
```

**This will work.**

Here the class Data contains only one field i.e. color. You can add more fields.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your answer further?

Comment: Bad code sniplet, bad practice. The Data is mutable in your example, so you don't need to put back the reference as value to map,because reference getting via get() will not change.